# can't construct LINQ statement

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of elements

```
List<int> StatusIDs
```

and I have a query

```
IQuerable<xxx> query
```

I want to create statement like:

```
query = query.Where(p=>p.StatusID == StatusID_1 || p.StatusID == StatusID_2 || ... p.StatusID == StatusID_n)
```

where StatusID_1, StatusID_2 ... StatusID_n - elements of StatusIDs. How to do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe you want this?

```
query.Where(p => StatusIDs.Contains(p.StatusID))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can perform an [inner join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx):

```
var result = from p in query
             join id in StatusIDs on p.StatusID equals id
             select p;
```